# Consecutive Reference Designators group into string with "-" separators of first and last seen(VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have Acccess VBA code that take a list of PCB Reference designators that are alpha numberically sorted and resorts them in the correct order of shown below. I would like help with getting the codes next step and looking to see if the numbers are consecutive and print out, in this case it would return "R1-R2,R10-R17, R26-R29,R191-R225,R294-R298"

```
Sub Resortalpha()

**strong text**
Dim Lne As String 'String of designators to resort
Dim i As Integer
Dim aryTextFile() As String 'Load string Lne into array
Dim newfile() As String 'Resort array that is sorted alpha numeric
Dim count As Integer 'counter to resort array based on length of variable in aryTextFile()

Lne = "R1,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,R15,R16,R17,R191,R192,R193,R194,R195,R196,R197,R198,R199,R2,R201,R202,R203,R204,R205,R206,R207,R208,R209,R210,R211,R212,R213,R214,R215,R216,R217,R218,R219,R220,R221,R222,R223,R224,R225,R26,R27,R28,R29,R294,R295,R296,R297,R298"
 
aryTextFile = Split(Lne, ",")
ReDim Preserve newfile(UBound(aryTextFile)) As String 'Used for a concatenation program that looks for a list of part numbers and concatenates references

count = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
    If Len(aryTextFile(i)) <= 2 Then
        newfile(count) = aryTextFile(i)
       count = count + 1
     End If
 Next i


For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
    If Len(aryTextFile(i)) = 3 Then
        newfile(count) = aryTextFile(i)
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
    If Len(aryTextFile(i)) = 4 Then
        newfile(count) = aryTextFile(i)
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i

 
newline = Join(newfile, ",")
strOut = newline

Debug.Print strOut' prints R1,R2,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,R15,R16,R17,R26,R27,R28,R29,R191,R192,R193,R194,R195,R196,R197,R198,R199,R200,R201,R202,R203,R204,R205,R206,R207,R208,R209,R210,R211,R212,R213,R214,R215,R216,R217,R218,R219,R220,R221,R222,R223,R224,R225,R294,R295,R296,R297,R298
End Sub
```

Comment: If all your items have the same "R" prefix then it would be easier to strip it off before sorting, and add it back at the end.  Then all your values would be in numeric order and the process would be simpler

Comment: Yeah I have stripping the R off and I have been trying that but getting the start and stop positions is what I am have trouble with gettting it to look like this  "R1-R2,R10-R17, R26-R29,R191-R225,R294-R298"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already sorted the values, I'm proceeding from that point.  If you pass `strOut` into the following function the values will be formatted as you need.  You could integrate this into your existing code, or leave it as a separate function:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function FormatDesignators(ByVal Designators As String) As String
   Dim d As Variant
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim GroupCount As Integer
   
   d = Replace(Designators, "R", "")
   d = Split(d, ",")
   FormatDesignators = "R" & d(LBound(d))
   
   For i = LBound(d) + 1 To UBound(d)
      If CInt(d(i)) <> CInt(d(i - 1)) + 1 Then
         If GroupCount >= 1 Then FormatDesignators = FormatDesignators & "-R" & d(i - 1)
         FormatDesignators = FormatDesignators & ",R" & d(i)
         GroupCount = 0
      Else
         GroupCount = GroupCount + 1
      End If
   Next

   If GroupCount >= 1 Then FormatDesignators = FormatDesignators & "-R" & d(UBound(d))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Included sorting in numeric order:

```vb
Sub FormatAsRanges()

    Dim Lne As String, arr, s
    Dim n As Long, v As Long, prev As Long, inRange As Boolean

    Lne = "R1,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,R15,R16,R17,R191,R192,R193,R194,R195," & _
          "R196,R197,R198,R199,R2,R201,R202,R203,R204,R205,R206,R207," & _
          "R208,R209,R210,R211,R212,R213,R214,R215,R216,R217,R218,R219,R220," & _
          "R221,R222,R223,R224,R225,R26,R27,R28,R29,R294,R295,R296,R297,R298"
     
    arr = ArraySort(Split(Replace(Lne, "R", ""), ",")) 'sort as numbers
    
    prev = -999 'dummy value
    For n = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        v = CLng(arr(n))
        If v - prev = 1 Then 'starting or continuing a range?
            inRange = True   'wait until range ends before adding anything
        Else
            If inRange Then           'ending a range ?
                s = s & "-R" & prev   'close out current range with previous item
                inRange = False
            End If
            s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, ",", "") & "R" & v  'add the current item
        End If
        prev = v
    Next n
    If inRange Then s = s & "-R" & prev 'close out last item if in a range
    
    Debug.Print s

End Sub

Function ArraySort(MyArray As Variant)
    Dim First As Long, last As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Temp
    First = LBound(MyArray)
    last = UBound(MyArray)
    For i = First To last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To last
            If CLng(MyArray(i)) > CLng(MyArray(j)) Then
                Temp = MyArray(j)
                MyArray(j) = MyArray(i)
                MyArray(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ArraySort = MyArray
End Function
```

If you have variable prefixes you can extract them like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim v
    For Each v In Array("A1", "AA23", "FFF4")
        Debug.Print v, Prefix(CStr(v))
    Next v
End Sub


'get the character prefix (up to the first digit)
Function Prefix(v As String) As String
    Dim rv As String, c As String, i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(v)
        c = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            rv = rv & c
        End If
    Next i
    Prefix = rv
End Function
```

Comment: OK I have a DNI(do not install list) that I would like to do something similar with.  Looks to be more difficult.

Comment: OK I have a DNI(do not install list) that I would like to do something similar with.  Looks to be more difficult.  LNE = AR15,AR2,AR3,AR4,AT3,AT4,C316,C319,C68,C76,FL14,FL15,FL16,FL17,FL18,FL6,J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6,L2,L3,L4,L5,T4,T5,T6,U38                                                         
 and make AR4-AR4, AR15, AT3-AT4, C68, C76, C316,C319, FL6, FL14-FL18, J1-J6, L2-L5, T4-T6, U38

Comment: Divide the list by prefix and run each group through the process above.  You'd need to make the prefix configurable (eg for the sorting Sub)

Comment: Tim I have been using the Left function to pull the designator type(R,C).  Is there a nifty way to check if the designator type contains 2 characters before the number, ex AR4.

Comment: See my edit - if you have more Q then start a new post.